# JavaFX EventFilter Implementation

Tags: java, javafx, eventfilter

I have tried implementing JavaFX `EventFilter` similar to this:

```
@FXML
public void leftButton() {
    leftButton.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
        new EventHandler < MouseEvent > () {

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Left Button pressed, String: " + leftString);
                    byte[] command = {
                        (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, panLeft, speedNormal, 0x00, endTx, 0x2B
                    };
                    //byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(upString);
                    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

                    sw.out.write(command);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    leftButton.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,
        new EventHandler < MouseEvent > () {

            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Left Button released, String: " + stopString);
                    byte[] command = {
                        (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) endTx, 0x0F
                    };

                    TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                        twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
                    sw.out.write(command);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
}
```

So that I write a string through my serial port when the `Button` is clicked and a different string is send when I release the `Button`.

I have two problems
1. when I first open the application, I have to press the `Button` twice before anything happens
2. for every additional click the action happens again. EG first click "HELLO" Second click "HELLO HELLO"

I suspect my problem is that my first click registers the `EventFilter` and then each subsequent event creates a new `EventFilter`

How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: The problem is not in the code you are showing. Consider constructing a small, runnable example, that Showcases the unexpected behaviour.

Comment: I think the problem is with your EventFilter's being inside `leftButton()`. When is this method called?

Comment: It is called every time I press or release the button.  `<Button id="leftButton" fx:id="leftButton" onAction="#leftButton"`

Answer (score 0):

> 1. when I first open the application, I have to press the Button twice before anything happens

You add your event filters inside the method `leftButton()` which is called on your button's action. So, the first time when you click on your button, there is no event filter attached to it and therefore nothing happens.

To overcome this, you can either move the code to `initialize()` or use separate methods to place these code and then use FXML to call them.

**On Press**

```
public void onPress() {
    try {
         System.out.println("Left Button pressed, String: " + leftString);
         byte[] command = { (byte) startTx, address, byteOne, panLeft, speedNormal, 0x00, endTx, 0x2B };
         TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
         twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
         sw.out.write(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**On Release**

```
public void onRelease() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Left Button released, String: " + stopString);
        byte[] command = {(byte) startTx, address, byteOne, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, (byte) endTx, 0x0F};
        TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());
        sw.out.write(command);
    } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**FXML**

```
<Button id="leftButton" fx:id="leftButton" onMousePressed="#onPress" onMouseReleased="#onRelease"/>
```

> 2. for every additional click the action happens again. EG first click "HELLO" Second click "HELLO HELLO"

Although, I am not sure but you seem to be writing to the same stream and therefore appending your data.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need event **filters**, you need to move the code inside the `leftButton()` method to a `initialize` method. Otherwise the method will add additional listeners every time it is called.

```
@FXML
private initialize() {
    leftButton.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
       ...
    );

    leftButton.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_RELEASED,
        ...
    );
}
```

If event **handlers** are sufficient, create 2 handlers and use register them from the fxml:

```
@FXML
private void leftButtonPressed() {
    ...
}

@FXML
private void leftButtonReleased() {
    ...
}
```

```xml
<Button fx:id="leftButton" onMousePressed="#leftButtonPressed" onMouseReleased="#leftButtonReleased"
```